# Intellij doesn't seem to be able to run my spock test

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, spock

I just created a new spring boot project and am trying to add spock testing. Here is my spock test:

```
package com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.ZonedDateTime

class AccountTest extends Specification {
    Account account;

    static Account getAccount() {
        Account result = new Account()

        return result;
    }

    void setup() {
        account = getAccount()
    }

    def "getStartTime should never be null"() {
        when: "retrieving a start date"
        ZonedDateTime start = account.getStartTime()

        then: "should never be null"
        start != null
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error

```
C:\Users\ThomH\.jdks\openjdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:63091,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\ThomH\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\ThomH\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\workspace\farragut-server\build\classes\java\test;C:\Users\ThomH\workspace\farragut-server\build\classes\groovy\test;C:\Users\ThomH\workspace\farragut-server\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.3\9e36c7517c4f872b69d0665e1dd46bd6d83c43b7\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-test\2.7.3\ce5a11117ac6c92d38ce071ff2273799862659b7\spring-boot-starter-test-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.3\23f7118584200cf9edd43140dc6252679047bee0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.3\6b0c093af667bf645cd5f49372e2a2540ae2855f\spring-boot-starter-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.7.3\ea46ce1fc8c0581f2455dcc43a11768660d87388\spring-boot-devtools-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-sql\3.0.9\a70eef193799ed892958ca00c6eda4f8710f656f\groovy-sql-3.0.9.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.spockframework\spock-core\2.1-groovy-3.0\2bd689be193cb26f42692eeef070e6669bebae3e\spock-core-2.1-groovy-3.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy\3.0.10\b92c72a758f468e64b55e38abe06afa873decdba\groovy-3.0.10.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.9.0\a44f7eba3ea214f6ec87ad9fccd3b2ac4681a4\junit-jupiter-api-5.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\2.2\3f2bd07716a31c395e2837254f37f21f0f0ab24b\hamcrest-core-2.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.3\38c88404d68926aaf6c0914199e8c5e766946de2\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.3\7a5998baaa05d5e7a9af7194a21f2ac3512ba7a0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.22\519d86b7ac9b8b6bb54739eb4eb73dc13a263b28\spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.3.22\fdab9b8d8df2e6a8fb90f2481c361bcf2c129567\spring-web-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.jupiter\junit-jupiter\5.8.2\5a817b1e63f1217e5c586090c45e681281f097ad\junit-jupiter-5.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\2.7.3\42924dceee5636b5c12ed36011cc333b40e1f756\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-test\2.7.3\34d3fbf68aa72beef1515ab4a439c23c8c41280e\spring-boot-test-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-test\5.3.22\48375b44c82945e12012ec56dc4090c805b4508b\spring-test-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.3.22\661fc01832716c7eedebf995c6841b2f7117c63d\spring-core-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jayway.jsonpath\json-path\2.7.0\f9d7d9659f2694e61142046ff8a216c047f263e8\json-path-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.xml.bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\48e3b9cfc10752fba3521d6511f4165bea951801\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.assertj\assertj-core\3.22.0\c300c0c6a24559f35fa0bd3a5472dc1edcd0111e\assertj-core-3.22.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest\2.2\1820c0968dba3a11a1b30669bb1f01978a91dedc\hamcrest-2.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-junit-jupiter\4.5.1\f81fb60bd69b3a6e5537ae23b883326f01632a61\mockito-junit-jupiter-4.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-core\4.5.1\ed456e623e5afc6f4cee3ae58144e5c45f3b3bf\mockito-core-4.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.1\6d842d0faf4cf6725c509a5e5347d319ee0431c3\jsonassert-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.9.0\8959725d90eecfee28acd7110e2bb8460285d876\xmlunit-core-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.3\b2806bdfae4cff6b82a174a68984a4cedd2d83f5\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.3\c5cfc6efad06811d5dd916e86c97989b08575b31\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.2\1b8783e98d4199c8fbcb46765fbfce02f41907fe\spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\c4179d48720a1e87202115fbed6089bdc4195405\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\8f6ea5daedc614f07a3654a455660145286f024e\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.10.Final\408fd5802391d8e6f619db9d7c6c0e27d49118c2\hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.22\1fdd8ac7f557ba12bb59086edfe3a9cdf6d918bf\spring-aspects-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.3\4c96169e8d71c9c41f07a40d011dbd41898180ac\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.7.3\3a8d641077565b7eaec3b2f91d5b83a6800f5895\spring-boot-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.3\a1e4a13b656182ba10b4c0c7848f91cd6f854fdf\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\8fde7fe2586328ac3c68db92045e1c8759125000\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.platform\junit-platform-engine\1.8.2\b737de09f19864bd136805c84df7999a142fec29\junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.platform\junit-platform-commons\1.8.2\32c8b8617c1342376fd5af2053da6410d8866861\junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.opentest4j\opentest4j\1.2.0\28c11eb91f9b6d8e200631d46e20a7f407f2a046\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.2\a231e0d844d2721b0fa1b238006d15c6ded6842a\apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\ad2f4c61aeb9e2a8bb5e4a3ed782cfddec52d972\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\f71c4ecc1a403787c963f68bc619b78ce1d2687b\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\d4884595d5aab5babdb00ddbd693b8fd36b5ec3c\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\56deb9ea2c93a7a556b3afbedd616d342963464e\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.65\bd70dfeb39cc83c6934be24fa377b21e541dbe76\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.65\a24c5f379b2ec343a167a83332b75c37f26b2ae7\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.65\d278157387e59a5f9b48091dcada22b7c74aed00\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.3.22\fdd59bb4795c7a399e95ec4a5c8b91103e3189fd\spring-context-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.3.22\2f9f00efbff8432f145ccffeb93e6a1819bac362\spring-aop-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.3.22\866c2022b5fef05b1702f4a07cfa5598660ce08a\spring-beans-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.3.22\c056f9e9994b18c95deead695f9471952d1f21d1\spring-expression-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.jupiter\junit-jupiter-params\5.8.2\ddeafe92fc263f895bfb73ffeca7fd56e23c2cce\junit-jupiter-params-5.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.22\811ace5e5eb379654ed96fd7844809db51af74a5\spring-jcl-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\6c62681a2f655b49963a5983b8b0950a6120ae14\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minidev\json-smart\2.4.8\7c62f5f72ab05eb54d40e2abf0360a2fe9ea477f\json-smart-2.4.8.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\99f53adba383cb1bf7c3862844488574b559621f\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.13\35ffee9c24b1c68b08d9207e1a2d3da1add6166\byte-buddy-1.12.13.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.12.13\5a4ed1c2eb9e8d7272b36b2b16757e5c653ab650\byte-buddy-agent-1.12.13.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.vaadin.external.google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\fa26d351fe62a6a17f5cda1287c1c6110dec413f\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\158f5c255cd3e4408e795b79f7c3fbae9b53b7ca\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.22\d50fc708ef9bade1d3fb64d529b8ff8cd5b625ba\spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\107cbdf0db6780a065f895ae9d8fbf3bb0e1c21f\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.3.22\abcefbf4895a3daf263cf385cc66e924db92d254\spring-orm-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.7.2\9547d1234cb380234066aef60129bb2ddfdc6347\spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.3.22\d0b3812ab20987a13f3a9ae7b4c54f619e034692\spring-tx-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\1e6cd0e5d9f9919c8c8824fb4d310b09a978a60e\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\e59ffdbc6ad09eeb33507b39ffcf287679a498c8\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\c4bd7e12a745c0e7f6cf98c45cdcdf482fd827ea\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\1e1c385990b258ff1a24c801e84aebbacf70eb39\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\3fe0bed568c62df5e89f4f174c101eab25345b6c\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\4741689214e9d1e8408b206506cbe76d1c6a7d60\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\17dd0fae2747d9a28c67bc9534108823d2376b46\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\ed46d81cef9c412a88caef405b58f93a678ff2ca\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\7198b3aac15285a49e218e08441c5f70af00fc51\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.13.3\a27014716e4421684416e5fa83d896ddb87002da\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.minidev\accessors-smart\2.4.8\6e1bee5a530caba91893604d6ab41d0edcecca9a\accessors-smart-2.4.8.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\45db7b69a8f1ec2c21eb7d4fc0ee729f53c1addc\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\cbbe1a62b0cc6c85972e99d52aaee350153dc530\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.11\a01230df5ca5c34540cdaa3ad5efb012f1f1f792\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\f42d6afa111b4dec5d2aea0fe2197240749a4ea6\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm\9.1\a99500cf6eea30535eeac6be73899d048f8d12a8\asm-9.1.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.vintage\junit-vintage-engine\5.9.0\b4980fe3c30b330ffa118fc1e732c804260d0bf6\junit-vintage-engine-5.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.h2database\h2\2.1.214\d5c2005c9e3279201e12d4776c948578b16bf8b2\h2-2.1.214.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.8\aa42edb39e624cbf8a5b33cb5c5e920027cee42b\byte-buddy-1.12.8.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.objenesis\objenesis\3.2\7fadf57620c8b8abdf7519533e5527367cb51f09\objenesis-3.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.platform\junit-platform-testkit\1.8.2\43c593ad99a975588d56b501fd4353065facebfc\junit-platform-testkit-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\20.1.0\2fcd1f3225bca0c4a7bc931142076f8c1e80993f\annotations-20.1.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm\9.2\81a03f76019c67362299c40e0ba13405f5467bff\asm-9.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\cglib\cglib-nodep\3.3.0\87271c95d5bc9e37e4981c9593ff14d470b6684b\cglib-nodep-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.13.2\8ac9e16d933b6fb43bc7f576336b8f4d7eb5ba12\junit-4.13.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.8.2\c598b4328d2f397194d11df3b1648d68d7d990e3\junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.junit.platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.8.2\c334fcee82b81311ab5c426ec2d52d467c8d0b28\junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar;C:\Users\ThomH\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\74548703f9851017ce2f556066659438019e7eb5\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account.AccountTest
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63091', transport: 'socket'
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account.AccountTest':
  1. No runnable methods

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:525)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.<init>(JUnit4.java:23)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Here's my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'

    // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.10'
    testImplementation platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.1-groovy-3.0")
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.0"

    // optional dependencies for using Spock
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.2"   // only necessary if Hamcrest matchers are used
    testRuntimeOnly 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.8' // allows mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces)
    testRuntimeOnly "org.objenesis:objenesis:3.2"      // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with ByteBuddy or CGLIB)

    // dependencies used by examples in this project
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:3.0.9"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

I found a bunch of similar issues that were resolved variously. Tried all of the things like

- Make certain the groovy directory is marked as a test sources root
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Run unit tests using IntelliJ IDA instead of gradle

Also found a similar intelliJ bug, but wanted to try here before going to intelliJ.

Ideas?

Comment: does it run from the command line? One thing i've had issues with in the past is attempting to mix gradle's `platform` with the Spring Dependency Management plugin. I'd suggest only using a single approach for managed dependencies within the project.

Comment: @BenM yes, it runs from the command line. Not sure what you mean by mixing. So how do you think I should proceed?

Comment: On thing, your groovy dependencies are misaligned. Spock 2.2 is out and uses Junit 5.9.0. 
In any case IntelliJ tries to run the task as JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 5. You could try to tell intelliJ to run the tests via `Gradle`. Which version of intellij are you using there was a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274589 in an older version.

Comment: @user16358266 Changed back to gradle, and upgrade to 2021.2.4 and it fixed the problem. Please write as ansnwer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to tell IntelliJ to run the tests via Gradle, this has the added advantage that the execution will match what you see in CI, especially if you have some additional config on the test task. It is a bit slower though.

There was a bug [IDEA-274589](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274589) in an older IntelliJ version, so upgrading to the fix version or newer will help.